# Design Patterns and OOP principle in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Question to solve:

"There are several types of accounting service Orders. The current solution for these orders is to create a new class for each type (based on work type e.g. audits or day-to-day work, whether the order is for priority client , and whether the order is a one off or regularly scheduled work). The full system has 66 * 2 * 2 of these classes (264 order classes!), with 8 of these (2*2*2) provided to you as an example – CPA would like you to find a way to reduce this class load without breaking the existing Order interface."

The Code related to the question:

```
 if (isScheduled) {
  if (1 == orderType) { 
    if (isCritical) {
      order =
          new FirstOrderTypeScheduled(
              id, clientID, date, criticalLoading, maxCountedEmployees, numQuarters);
    } else {
      order = new Order66Scheduled(id, clientID, date, maxCountedEmployees, numQuarters);
    }
  } else if (2 == orderType) { // 2 is audit
    if (isCritical) {
      order = new CriticalAuditOrderScheduled(id, clientID, date, criticalLoading, numQuarters);
    } else {
      order = new NewOrderImplScheduled(id, clientID, date, numQuarters);
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
} else {
  if (1 == orderType) {
    if (isCritical) {
      order = new FirstOrderType(id, clientID, date, criticalLoading, maxCountedEmployees);
    } else {
      order = new Order66(id, clientID, date, maxCountedEmployees);
    }
  } else if (2 == orderType) {
    if (isCritical) {
      order = new CriticalAuditOrder(id, clientID, date, criticalLoading);
    } else {
      order = new NewOrderImpl(id, clientID, date);
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

So, there are a few types of classes given (8 classes) which are indicated in the above question. What I want to ask is, amongst the design principles and OO design principles (SOLID), is there a method that I should apply in order to solve the above question? (I am  thinking of using Bridge Pattern)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the *existing order interface*? And where did you get this question from?

Comment: This looks like a job for the builder pattern to me.  Maybe implement with a Decorator Pattern.  (And "Bridge" is a driver, like device driver.  Nope, unless you're parsing something really complex.)

Comment: @markspace Thanks for your reply! how should I integrate Builder with Decorator? Could you please give me some hints? Also How would using builder pattern reduce the class load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creational design patterns that might help you are the Factory and the Builder.

If you have an interface (let's say IOrder) and multiple implementations you can use the factory pattern:

you will have an OrderFactory class which will create orders based on some parameters, it can be something like this:

```java
public class OrderFactory {

   public IOrder createOrder( boolean isScheduled, int orderType, boolean isCritical){
      // here will be the logic from your post and the order will be returned
   }

}
```

with the Factory pattern, you can also have multiple nested factories, which I think could be the case in your example - this is called the abstract factory. This is more complicated, you can check an example here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/abstract-factory-pattern/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! by the way, how does Factory pattern reduce the class load? Isn't class load in the question meaning that we need to mitigate class creation for a new type of order?

Comment: I'm not sure I've got the question.
The main advantage of the Abstract Factory Pattern is the separation of concerns. You can have a single class that will decide what types of orders must be created for scheduled and another class that will decide for critical orders.. so you are breaking the logic into multiple smaller classes, instead of having a huge function with a lot of ifs

Comment: Actually, it is our job to interpret the above question, so "class load" in the question can be interpreted in many ways. Someone asked a student what to do for that question and this was the answer:
"We need to improve the current solution such that, when the system scales up in size less classes are created(my interpretation) for the orders at least."
How would you match the Abstract Factory Pattern towards the question above? since I need to explain why I used that pattern in order to reduce the class load...

Comment: well, I think this depends on the 8 given implementations: if they are all doing the same or very similar steps but in a different order, you can try to use the Decorator Pattern. With this, you can add the functionality of a certain object at runtime, without necessarily creating a separate class for it.  Take a look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-decorator-pattern-set-2-introduction-and-design/

Comment: Yeap I saw that post already :) If I use the decorator pattern, do I still need to use that if/else statements stated above? How should I initialize a class depending on the situation?

Comment: It depends on your Order implementationsand the base interface, please consult the second article (link) to see if this pattern can help you. If your usecasee allows you, you can only have a SheduledDecorator and a CriticalDecorator or something like this

Comment: I will consult the second article and comment the link when its ready :)